# Blackberry context menu close event

Tags: javascript, contextmenu, blackberry-webworks, blackberry-10

I develop a javascript blackberry-webworks based application. I've defined my own context for menu ([blackberry.ui.contextmenu.defineCustomContext](http://developer.blackberry.com/html5/apis/blackberry.ui.contextmenu.html#.defineCustomContext)) and added several items. It can be opened at appropriate nodes but i can't determine when it is being closed.

Is it possible to get event when context menu is being closed? Or is there any property/method that gives context menu state (like "opened"/"closed")?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the only event you can get a handle on is the window.onContextMenu event, which fires when the menu is requested by the client/user.

From the docs ( https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/apis/blackberry.ui.contextmenu.html )
*"Context information is available from the window object through a contextmenu event "window.oncontextmenu". This event is triggered whenever there is a context menu request from the client. This event provides all the contextual information needed to store the context yourself and save what element the context menu was triggered on. This allows you to perform a multitude of different actions once a context menu has been requested."*

Comment: Yes, I've seen it. But I'd like to save some info (e.g. target node) before menu appears and clear this information after closing. Still, thanks for your response, @chadtatro.